# How to choose which div to show when is different orientation?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created this simple slideshow but I want to know how can I select a different div by orientation. So for example now is reading in portrait and landscape "container-gallery" but if I want as this div to be show only in portrait and "container-gallery-landscape" only in landscape with landscape images how can I reach this?

here is my fiddle to have a look over my code and how it is working          http://jsfiddle.net/25q253Lu/

jQuery

```
    var currentIndex = 0,
      items = $('.container-gallery div'),
      itemAmt = items.length;

    function movingItems() {
      var item = $('.container-gallery div').eq(currentIndex);
      items.hide();
      item.css('display','inline-block');
    }

    $('.next').click(function() {
      currentIndex += 1;
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      movingItems();
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
      currentIndex -= 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
      }
      movingItems();
    });
```

**My Solution**

I've created a different `var itemsLandscape` and then I associated my landscape div because if you associate for the same var different values only the last one will be considered valid. Example: var items =  4 and var items = 5 then var items = 5 because first value is null.

```
var currentIndex = 0,
          items = $('.container-gallery div'),
          itemsLandscape = $('.container-gallery-landscape div'),
          itemAmt = items.length;

        function movingItems() {
          var item = $('.container-gallery div').eq(currentIndex);
          var itemLandscape = $('.container-gallery-landscape div').eq(currentIndex);
          items.hide();
          itemsLandscape.hide();
          item.css('display','inline-block');
          itemLandscape.css('display','inline-block');
        }

        $('.next').click(function() {
          currentIndex += 1;
          if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
          }
          movingItems();
        });

        $('.prev').click(function() {
          currentIndex -= 1;
          if (currentIndex < 0) {
            currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
          }
          movingItems();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a CSS [`orientation` media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation):

```
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    .container-gallery-landscape {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    .container-gallery {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And then, if you need to know which div is showing at any given time, you can use `css` to find out:

```
if ($(".container-gallery").is(":visible")) {
    // It's visible, we must be in portrait
}
```

Here's an example; bring it up on an iPad or similar, rotate into each orientation, and click the button:

```js
$("#the-btn").on("click", function() {
  if ($(".container-gallery").is(":visible")) {
    alert(".container-gallery visible");
  } else {
    alert(".container-gallery not visible, so presumably .container-gallery-landscape is");
  }
});
```

```css
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .container-gallery-landscape {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .container-gallery {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-gallery">container-gallery</div>
<div class="container-gallery-landscape">container-gallery-landscape</div>
<input type="button" id="the-btn" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is the CSS part which I thought so but I am thinking of javascript part

Comment: @FlapJack: I'm not following, why do you need a "JavaScript part" for this?

Comment: because if I use this I can use the arrow only in one orientation

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I don't know what you mean with that. There are 2 classes not one.    `if ($(".container-gallery").is(":visible")) {
    // It's visible, we must be in portrait
} else { what? }`

Comment: @FlapJack: With the CSS above, `else { /* the other one is visible */}` If there's a possibility they'll *both* be hidden (some page mode where you don't have that part at all), you'll need to allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for that. Example :

```css
 @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
   .landscape {
     display: none;
   }
 }
 @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
   .portrait {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="landscape">lanscape content</div>
<div class="portrait">portrait content</div>
```

Comment: Using this method will give me access for left and right arrows only in one orientation